# Can't update ubuntu 12.10 in Lenovo G580

Tags: 12.10, apt, updates, update-manager

I'm above mentioned laptop running ubuntu 12.10.When i issue `sudo apt-get update` it shows

```
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213) precise Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213) precise Release
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213) precise/main i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213) precise/restricted i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213) precise/main Translation-en_IN
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213) precise/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213) precise/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213) precise/restricted Translation-en
```

My machine configuration is intel i5 32 bit machine.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open software & update manager
uncheck the CD/DVD updates installation
[image]

Comment: in my system there is not such option! that particular box is empty

Comment: maybe this http://i.stack.imgur.com/tBPRz.png

Comment: yes something like that! it s already unchecked

Comment: my first tab is http://postimg.org/image/68p2462sz/ second tab is http://postimg.org/image/qfbeh6uc5/

Comment: in the 2nd tap 'Other Software' 
uncheck cdrom with ubuntu 12.04 'precise pangolin' 
then update

Comment: it s already unchecked!

Comment: the 2nd line in 'Other Software' check out your picture & what i wrote